# new items destroy layout of grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

By refreshing the items within a grid sometimes it happen that the grid shows completely crazy:

[image]

That's how I update the data every time. The instance of the Grid stays the same:

```
dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(newItems);
grid.setItems(dataProvider);
```

Does someone have an idea whether I do something wrong or there is a bug within Vaadin?

---

Complete code:

```
    if (!columnsIntialized) {   
        for (Method method : gridProperties) {
            Column<T> column = grid.addColumn(data -> {
                Object value = method.invoke(data);
                return getFormattedValue(value, method.getReturnType());
            });

            String resourceKey = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(GridProperties.class).resourceKey();
            column.setKey(resourceKey);
            column.setHeader(AppResources.getString(resourceKey));
            
            int width = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(GridProperties.class).width();
            if (width == -1) {
                column.setAutoWidth(true);
            } else {
                column.setWidth(width + "px");
            }
        }
        columnsIntialized = true;
    }
    
    dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(items);
    grid.setItems(dataProvider);
    grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
```

Comment: Can you show how you have created the grid and defined the columns?

Comment: I changed the code above, because unfortunately it as not possible for me to format the code as answer :)

Comment: Why would you want to put that code as answer? Has the block "complete code" _fixed_ your problem and is is supposed to be an answer? Or is this the actually failing code producing the described problem?

Comment: This is currently the failing code which produces the described problem.

Comment: I found out that the layout issue occures if data is loaded, some new data is added and the before defined columns are changed (some columns become visible and some are hidden). Does anyone also had this situation?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out, and if not, could you create a simple test application that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @AnnaKoskinen I was able to reproduce it. See the following bug: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/2489

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin 22.0.3 is scheduled to be released on Monday with the fix.